# Materialize label gets overlapped in production env

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm using materialize for my web page, and the problem is the label gets overlapped with the field over the text, this issue occurs only in the production environment, but works fine in the develop

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <%= f.text_field :phone, id: "phno", "data-parsley-error-message" => "Please enter your phone number.", required: true %>
  <label for="phno">Phone</label>
</div>
```

Comment: could you post screenshots?

Comment: I have provided the part of code where i get the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but only when loading pages via ajax. According to the comments on [this issue](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/180), the code that worked for me is:

```
$(function () {
  Materialize.updateTextFields();
});
```

They said the problem was solved, but even in the last release I still got the error. Anyway, the code above fixes the bug.

Comment: but i'm not using any ajax request in this form.

Comment: @Johnson it seems to be a bug, anyway just executing the `updateTextFields` function will fix your problem

Comment: have tried both the methods. but not getting the expected thing. @victor, any other way to solve this issue, and i'm using rails 4 with materialize and  most likely this issue raised after pre compiling  assets in production

Answer (score 0):

Just add class `active` for your label:

```
<label for="phno" class="active">Phone</label>
```

another way to resolve this issue is to reinitialize label with javascript function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Materialize.updateTextFields();
});
```

Comment: have already tried the active class, which is ok when the text field is prefilled  or autofill on page load, for but i'm getting this issue in normal pages where i don't have any auto fill ,if i use this active class for those pages the label permanently stays active even if i don't enter any text in it.